# Command failed: transaction submit Error: Error while submitting tx

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli

I have minted a token to the testnet and now i want to sent it to deadalus testnet wallet but i am getting error. And the steps which i am following is this.

**Make a transaction**

`cardano-cli transaction build-raw  --fee 177381  --tx-in 8e6ece3c2fde93fb741bee62ececb886c1108d3a1c287ab29cc6a887c33b757e#0 --tx-out addr_test1qp62uukdt5q588ggeu0j7hwe2jdjrqecmvt6mc4hy4luvlvvdm7hkdy4dtdmsvxg3gc0ddg52etkffmf0sx4rl5zwv7sg5vcyv+"2 $(cat policy/tokens/policy.id).eduladderTestCoin"  --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+"998 $(cat policy/tokens/policy.id).eduladderTestCoin" --out-file token_tx.raw`

**Create the protocol.**

`cardano-cli  query protocol-parameters \ --testnet-magic 1097911063 \ --out-file protocol.json`

**Get the fee.**

`cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \ --tx-body-file token_tx.raw \ --tx-in-count 1 \ --tx-out-count 1 \ --witness-count 1 \ --byron-witness-count 0 \ --testnet-magic 1097911063  \ --protocol-params-file protocol.json`

**Again with the updated fee.**

`cardano-cli transaction build-raw  --fee 177381  --tx-in 8e6ece3c2fde93fb741bee62ececb886c1108d3a1c287ab29cc6a887c33b757e#0 --tx-out addr_test1qp62uukdt5q588ggeu0j7hwe2jdjrqecmvt6mc4hy4luvlvvdm7hkdy4dtdmsvxg3gc0ddg52etkffmf0sx4rl5zwv7sg5vcyv+"2 $(cat policy/tokens/policy.id).eduladderTestCoin"  --tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+"998 $(cat policy/tokens/policy.id).eduladderTestCoin" --out-file token_tx.raw`

**Now sign the transaction.**

`cardano-cli transaction sign \ --signing-key-file payment.skey \ --signing-key-file policy/policy.skey \ --testnet-magic 1097911063 \ --tx-body-file alien_babies_tx.raw \ --out-file token_tx.raw.signed`

**Now sent the same**

`cardano-cli transaction submit \ --tx-file  token_tx.raw.signed \ --testnet-magic 1097911063`

But i am getting the following error.

`Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (OutputTooSmallUTxO [(Addr Testnet (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "74ae72cd5d01439d08cf1f2f5dd9549b218338db17ade2b7257fc67d")) (StakeRefBase (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "8c6efd7b34956adbb830c88a30f6b514565764a7697c0d51fe82733d"))),Value 0 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "c5edbeaed052fa6e3e3f1ced8e39fdb9900b910622ead746ee938cff"},fromList [("eduladderTestCoin",2)])]),SNothing),(Addr Testnet (KeyHashObj (KeyHash "6baa0d059efc68aefaf4d30c639d62a894b2568b874e06d4f5a39c15")) StakeRefNull,Value 0 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "c5edbeaed052fa6e3e3f1ced8e39fdb9900b910622ead746ee938cff"},fromList [("eduladderTestCoin",998)])]),SNothing)]))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 9811135 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "c5edbeaed052fa6e3e3f1ced8e39fdb9900b910622ead746ee938cff"},fromList [("eduladderTestCoin",1000)])])) (Value 188865 (fromList [(PolicyID {policyID = ScriptHash "c5edbeaed052fa6e3e3f1ced8e39fdb9900b910622ead746ee938cff"},fromList [("eduladderTestCoin",1000)])])))))])`

How do i debug this? What wrong is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is probably you're missing the minimum amount of Ada required to be sent along with any tokens.By design this is required to limit the overall size of the ledger.

See more info on this here:
https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/minimum-ada-value-requirement

> It is impossible to make outputs containing only custom tokens

> Requiring some amount of ada to be included in every UTXO (where that
> amount is based on the size of the UTXO, in bytes), limits the maximum
> total size taken up by UTXO entries on the ledger at any given time.

Comment: I have tried with ada in it as well. But that also not working attaching the command below `cardano-cli transaction build-raw 
--fee 177381 
--tx-in 8e6ece3c2fde93fb741bee62ececb886c1108d3a1c287ab29cc6a887c33b757e#0 --tx-out addr_test1qp62uukdt5q588ggeu0j7hwe2jdjrqecmvt6mc4hy4luvlvvdm7hkdy4dtdmsvxg3gc0ddg52etkffmf0sx4rl5zwv7sg5vcyv+2+"2 $(cat policy/tokens/policy.id).eduladderTestCoin" 
--tx-out $(cat payment.addr)+9633752+"998 $(cat policy/tokens/policy.id).eduladderTestCoin"
--out-file token_tx.raw
`

Comment: the "2" for the ada in your first output probably needs to be "2000000" because it's in lovelace

Comment: It is not in ada it is in lovelace.

Comment: okay right, but 2 lovelace is too little then - you'll need to send a minimum of around ~1.6 Ada - which is 1600000 lovelace - together with the token

Comment: Okey. The transaction was successfull.